Optuna XGBoost not using all of Mac's CPU
I am running Optuna with mySQL to attempt to get parallelization and use more of my Mac's CPU. When I would run GridSearchCV for example, my user CPU usage would go up to 90% and fans would kick in. But when I use Optuna, I get around 30% and no fans. This indicates that it is not being utilized.
I tried using mySQL and distribution to get two processing running on VSCode's Jupyter Notebook. The way I did this was making two copies of my notebook on different kernels and then running the optimization code on the same SQL database by loading a study. Maybe this is not the right way to do it? Since in the example they ran foo.py on two terminals?
Here is my code:
def objective(trial, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    # Define the hyperparameter search space
    params = {
        'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 100, 5000),
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 20),
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 0.2),
        'subsample': trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.7, 1.0),
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.6, 1.0),
        'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 15),
        'gamma': trial.suggest_float('gamma', 0.0, 0.4),
        'lambda': trial.suggest_float('lambda', 1e-8, 1.0, log=True),
        'alpha': trial.suggest_float('alpha', 1e-8, 1.0, log=True)
    }

    # Initialize and train the model
    xgb = XGBRegressor(**params)
    xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Predict and calculate metrics
    y_pred = xgb.predict(X_test)
    error = max_percent_error(y_test, y_pred)
    return error  # Return the error to minimize

if __name__ == "__main__":
    study = optuna.load_study(study_name="example", storage="mysql://root@localhost/example")

    # Perform the optimization for each category and target
    for category in train_test_splits:
        for target_name in train_test_splits[category]:
                    if target_name in best_params_dict:
                        continue
                    print(f"Running Optuna optimization for target: {target_name} in category: {category}")

                    X_train = train_test_splits[category][target_name]['X_train']
                    y_train = train_test_splits[category][target_name]['y_train']
                    X_test = train_test_splits[category][target_name]['X_test']
                    
                    y_test = train_test_splits[category][target_name]['y_test']
                    
                    # Optimize the study with distributed computing
                    study.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test), 
                                n_trials=1900, n_jobs=-1)

                    # Store the best parameters found for this target
                    best_params = study.best_params
                    best_params_dict[category][target_name] = best_params

                    # Train the final model with the best parameters
                    xgb_best = XGBRegressor(**best_params)
                    xgb_best.fit(X_train, y_train)

                    # Evaluate the model with the test set
                    y_pred = xgb_best.predict(X_test)
                    test_max_percent_error = max_percent_error(y_test, y_pred)
                    test_r2_score = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

                    print(f"Best Results for {target_name}:")
                    print(f"  Best Parameters: {best_params}")
                    print(f"  Test Max Percent Error: {test_max_percent_error:.4f}%")
                    print(f"  Test R^2: {test_r2_score:.4f}\n")


thank you
